Spit a table of arrays into table with rows for each element of the arrays
I am trying to find the most efficient way in Snowflake to split a table of arrays into a table with all the elements into individual rows.
So a table having the rows
row 1: ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
row 2: ["jkl"]
row 3: ["mno", "pqr"]

Should return (individual rows)
"abc"
"def"
"ghi"
"jkl"
"mno"
"pqr"

Is there any method to do this without casting to strings and performing string manipulation?

You could try using FLATTEN

You may try to use FLATTEN method.
SELECT FLATTEN(your_array_column) FROM your_array_table;

Official Document: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten

you can use FLATTEN along with LATERAL or TABLE. Something like
select node.value as value
from mytable,
lateral flatten(column_holding_array) node;

select node.value as value
from mytable,
table(flatten(column_holding_array)) node;

the datatype of your column holding array should be type of array, else you will need to explicitly cast it to json using parse_json function.
select node.value as value
from mytable,
lateral flatten(parse_json(column_holding_array)) node;
    
select node.value as value
from mytable,
table(flatten(parse_json(column_holding_array))) node;

